# Swift: How to call a method located in ViewController from @main located in AppDelegate?

Tags: swift, program-entry-point, entry-point

I´m new to Swift and struggling with the entry point.

Used versions: Swift 5.5.2 +
IOS 15.3.1

I´ve created a method in ViewController which simply should show a word in a label. This method have to be called from a main function. According to my understanding
the main function has to be implemented in AppDelegate after @main.

Following my code.

**AppDelegate:**

```
@main struct myApp {
    static func main(){
        let newClass = ViewController()
        newClass.viewText()
    }
}
```

**ViewController:**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var labelText: UILabel!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    func viewText() {
        let word = "hello"
        labelText.text = String(word)
    }
}
```

By running the App I get the following *error message* which occurs in the line `labelText.text = String(word)`:

*Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value*

Your help is really appreciated.

Comment: An `@IBOutlet` indicates that you are using `UIKit/Storyboard`. On the other hand `@main struct` is for a command line interface, an app without Storyboard or SwiftUI. And please get used to the naming convention to name structs and classes with starting uppercase letter.

Comment: You are not supposed to call your view controller like that and I am pretty sure you shouldn't instantiate it like that either. Call viewText from viewDidLoad instead

Comment: @vadian thank for the explanation. And yes I will use the right naming convention next time.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson thanks! This is exactly what I have looked for. Calling the method from viewDidLoad works. I had a misunderstanding of how to call a method automatically when opening the app.

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out in the comments of your question, the @main is not meant for UI development, it is for [CLI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface) development (Command Line Interface).

I am not 100% sure what you mean with that you have a label which has a method that needs to be run on main, so I'm making some assumptions here on what you mean.
If you mean that the label should be tappable and run an action, then I would recommend you use an [UIButton](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton) for that.

Maybe you've heard somewhere that all UI needs to be run on Main and this is what you've meant, than I would say that at this stage you don't need to worry about that. By default the app is run on main, unless you actively do something to change this. Please forgive me in assuming this, but my assumption is that you are rather new to iOS development and so I would like to suggest that you get familiar with the basics first; e.g. setting up a basic UI and pressing a button with an action.

I would suggest you start off with building a simple [Hello, World! iOS](https://www.google.com/search?q=hello+world+ios) application and take it from there.

Comment: Thank you. And sorry for such a question. You're completely right. I'm new to Swift and learning it. I'm sure that the quality of my questions will improve with the time. ;) My problem has been solved by vadian. I was focused to the @main as entry point which was the wrong direction for my problem. I didn't know that this works only for CLI.

Comment: @diniska don't worry about that, we all had to start somewhere. Good that you look for help and also that you got the correct solution! Good luck! :)